# Has selected attribute been set for option check with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, attr

I'm trying to find out whether a user has chosen an option in a select box already (after a form was submitted), vs. if he hasn't.

Example:

```
<select>
 <option value="foo">foo</option>
 <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

(/\ user hasn't selected anything)

```
<select>
 <option value="foo">foo</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

(/\ user has selected an option before he submitted the form).

I've been experimenting with (all in jQuery):

```
$(this).attr('selected');
// returns true or false, regardless of whether the selected has explicitly been set

$(this).prop('selected');
// return 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'

$(this).is(':selected');
// returns true or false, regardless of whether the selected has explicitly been set

if( typeof( $(this).attr('selected') ) != 'undefined' ) {
// returns true or false, regardless of whether the selected has explicitly been set
```

In short: how do I check whether the selected="selected" 'thing' exists on an option element?

Comment: an <option> element as one of the children of a <select> element, exactly like in the examples above the problem definition. Given that $(this).attr('selected') works as supposed, I suppose that the selector itself is okay.

Comment: To check the state of an element, using properties is better than attributes. So I would use `prop`. But that `TypeError` is so weird, can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wcuh1cgt/4/

Comment: Ah, the problem with `$("select option").prop('selected')` (and `attr`) is that it says if the first `option` is selected, instead of returning the first selected `option`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a particular option is checked using the following statement

```
$("select option:selected").length>0 //if that option is selected
```

**UPDATE**

```
$("select option[value = '*value goes here*']:selected").length>0 //if that option is selected
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ocev927y/1/)

Comment: Note this doesn't check if a particular option is checked, it checks if any option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
$('#mySelect').on('change',function() {
    if($('#mySelect option:selected')) {
    alert("selected: "+ $('#mySelect').val());
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aLmr7g19/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following html...

```html
<select>
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

...the problem is that the first option will be selected by default.

Therefore, you won't be able to know if the user really want to select that option, or if he skipped it and didn't select anything.

Instead, suggest using something like the following:

```css
select > .placeholder{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="" class="placeholder" selected disabled>
    Select an option...
  </option>
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

Then, to know if the user has chosen an option, checking `value` will be enough:

```js
!!mySelect.value;    // If the user hasn't chosen any option,
                     // `mySelect.value === ''` in vanilla-js

!!$(mySelect).val(); // If the user hasn't chosen any option,
                     // `$(mySelect).val() === null` in jQuery 1.8.3+
                     // `$(mySelect).val() === ''` in previous jQuery
```